# Find whether a word is in a rational expression

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata

> You are given a word $w$ and a rational expression $R$ ($R$ is represented as a binary tree). Find an efficient algorithm that says whether $w \in L(R)$ or not.

I think I found a quadratic algorithm. First let denote $n$ the size of $R$ (i.e. the number of nodes). Then apply Glushkov's algorithm. So we get an automata that recognize $L(R)$ in time $O(n^2)$. Now just do a BFS to see if this automata accepts $w$. Hence this algorithm is in $O(n^2)$.

Now my question is: is it possible to do any better? Is there a way to solve this problem without computing the automata that recognized $L(R)$?

Comment: The complexity should depend both on the size of $R$ and of the length of $w$.

Comment: Given a regular expression of size $n$, you should be able to construct an equivalent NFA in linear time $O(n)$. You can then simulate the NFA on a word $w$ in time $O(n|w|)$.